# Conversion of rule to list values

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I convert the this rule to a list:

```
input = {1 -> {71.52, 55.33}};
```

to:

```
output = {71.52, 55.33}
```

Comment: [ReplaceAll](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html): `1 /. input`

Comment: Thank you. So this is the same as `ReplaceAll[1, input]`. But what is the meaning of the expression 1?

Comment: Use the answer by @Szabolcs.  But in this simple case, you could use `input[[1, 2]]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For versions before 10.0, use [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html)

```
Replace[1, input]
(* {71.52, 55.33} *)
```

I prefer to avoid `ReplaceAll` when `Replace` is appropriate. `ReplaceAll` works at all levels in an expression and is thus less predictable (or it makes a bigger mess if there's a bug in my code).  Consider if you can potentially have multiple non-atomic keys in the rule list, some of which are sub-parts of others, e.g. `{1 -> ..., a[1] -> ...}`.

For 10.0 or later versions, use [`Lookup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html)

```
Lookup[input, 1]
(* {71.52, 55.33} *)
```

`Lookup` is better for this use because it tells you if the key is missing from `input`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can convert list of rules into list of values, in the one of following four ways:

```
Last @@@ input
input[[All, 2]]
input /. Rule -> (#2 &)
Values@input
```

Answer (score 2):

it could be convenient to use `Association` for this, depending on what you are actually doing..

```
  Association[input][1]
```

> {71.52, 55.33}