# Code Review: ECDSA for Mathematica

Tags: programming, code-review, cryptography

The code below contains functions related to ECDSA (Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm) with standard parameters `secp256k1`. The implementation is based on several ideas spread over the internet and a quick overview of the algorithm is available at [GitHub: ECDSA-Mathematica](https://github.com/MarkMessa/ECDSA-Mathematica). Briefly, the code is capable of:

- generate random private/public key pairs
- signature generation and verification

For validation purposes I used [jsrsasign](https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/sample-ecdsa.html) which is an opensource cryptographic library for JavaScript. The test-vectors I've used so far worked fine and are available at [GitHub: ECDSA-Mathematica/Test-Vectors.txt](https://github.com/MarkMessa/ECDSA-Mathematica/blob/master/Test-Vectors.txt).

**Question**
At the moment, I consider it more important to optimize the code for readability instead of performance. That way it would be much easier to detect hidden bugs or make it more general. Therefore:

- Does it follow the best practices for coding and comments?
- Is it possible to improve its readability?

---

Usage example:

```
(* Load Package *)
In[1]:= Get[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],"ECDSA.m"}]];

(* generate a random private key *)
In[2]:= d = randomPrivateKeyECDSA[]
Out[2]:= 93602568143572437497047345193536924976274605889652076707509844737444328626670

(* generate the public key associated with private key d *)
In[3]:= {xh,yh}=publicKeyECDSA[d]
Out[3]:= {87943153917328339238098758968986858868870060847632433257348495687910286253282, 114510692297125386214880916984900906876306824610921820870708215390655128572828}

(* find the hash of a message *)
In[4]:= z=Hash["Hello World!","SHA256"]
Out[4]:= 57676413081093003148005107550719583540116985236696423860923466490497932824681

(* sign the message hash *)
In[5]:= {r,s}=signECDSA[z,d]
Out[5]:= {52645229419831756461156602966389193516169924018897850564955063216321799997576, 105208277479664712928314923396354361130135526252419945028148626557358697529330}

(* verify if the signature is correct *)
In[6]:= verifySignECDSA[z,{xh,yh},{r,s}]
Out[6]:= True

(* verify if a random signature is correct *)
In[7]:= verifySignECDSA[z,{xh,yh},{randomPrivateKeyECDSA[],randomPrivateKeyECDSA[]}]
Out[7]:= False
```

'ECDSA.m' package file:

```
(*
ECDSA for Mathematica 9
Package for signature generation and verification using ECDSA (elliptic curve digital signature algorithm) with parameters secp256k1.
*)

BeginPackage["ECDSA`"];

    ecPointModQ::usage="ecPointModQ[{a, b}, {x, y}, p] returns True if (x, y) is a coordinate of the elliptic curve E(Fp):y^2 = x^3 + a.x + b (mod p)";

    ecAddMod::usage="ecAddMod[{a, b}, {x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, p] returns the elliptic curve group point addition P1(x1, y1) + P2(x2, y2) over the finite field Fp. \n- The characteristic of the field must be a prime p. \n- The function accepts and returns {\[Infinity],\[Infinity]} for the group identity 0. \n- It returns {} if either point does not lie on the elliptic curve.";

    ecProductMod::usage="ecProductMod[{a, b}, Q, k, p] returns the scalar product k.Q in the abelian group of points on the elliptic curve E(Fp):y^2 = x^3 + a.x + b. This algorithm uses the binary representation of k to convert the problem into a series of doublings and additions in E(Fp).";

    secp256k1::usage = "The elliptic curve domain parameters (p, a, b, xg, yg, n, h) over Fp associated with a Koblitz curve secp256k1.";

    randomPrivateKeyECDSA::usage="randomPrivateKeyECDSA[] returns a random private key for ECDSA with parameters secp256k1.";

    publicKeyECDSA::usage="publicKeyECDSA[d] returns the public key associated with the private key integer d.";

    signECDSA::usage="signECDSA[z, d] returns the signature {r, s} of the integer z and the private key integer d using ECDSA with parameters secp256k1. Usually z is the hash of a message.";

    verifySignECDSA::usage="verifySignECDSA[z, {xh, yh}, {r, s}] returns True if the signature {r, s} of the integer z is associated with the public key {xh, yh}.";


    Begin["`Private`"];

        ecPointModQ[{a_,b_},{x_,y_},p_]:=Mod[PowerMod[x,3,p]+a x+b-PowerMod[y,2,p],p]==0;

        ecAddMod[{a_,b_},P1:{x1_,y1_},P2:{x2_,y2_},p_]:=Module[{m,x3,y3,w},

            (* Handle identity cases *)
            If[x1==\[Infinity],Return[P2]];
            If[x2==\[Infinity],Return[P1]];

            (* Q1 + (-Q1) = \[Infinity] *)
            If[x1==x2&&Mod[y1+y2,p]==0,Return[{\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}]];

            (* Verify that the points lie on the curve *)
            If[!ecPointModQ[{a,b},P1,p],Return[{}]];
            If[!ecPointModQ[{a,b},P2,p],Return[{}]];

            (* If doubling a point *)
            If[P1==P2,
                (* Check for vertical tangent *)
                If[y1==0,Return[{\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}]];
                (* Compute the slope of the tangent *)
                w=PowerMod[2 y1,-1,p];
                m=Mod[(3 x1^2+a)*w,p];
                ,
                (* else compute the slope of the chord *)
                w=PowerMod[x2-x1,-1,p];
                m=Mod[(y2-y1)*w,p];
            ];

            x3=Mod[m^2-x1-x2,p];
            y3=Mod[m(x1-x3)-y1,p];
            Return[{x3,y3}];
        ];

        ecProductMod[{a_,b_},Q_,k_,p_]:=Module[{i,R,S},
            (* Verify that the point lie on the curve *)
            If[!ecPointModQ[{a,b},Q,p],Return[{}]];

            i=k;R={\[Infinity],\[Infinity]};S=Q;
            While[i!=0,
                If[EvenQ[i],
                    i=Quotient[i,2];
                    S=ecAddMod[{a,b},S,S,p];
                    ,
                    i=i-1;
                    R=ecAddMod[{a,b},R,S,p];
                ];
            ];
            Return[R];
        ];

        secp256k1={
        "p"->(2^256-2^32-2^9-2^8-2^7-2^6-2^4-1),
        "a"->0,"b"->7,
        "xg"->55066263022277343669578718895168534326250603453777594175500187360389116729240,
        "yg"->32670510020758816978083085130507043184471273380659243275938904335757337482424,
        "n"->115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337,
        "h"->1};

        randomPrivateKeyECDSA[]:=Module[{n="n"/.secp256k1},Random[Integer,{1,n-1}]];

        publicKeyECDSA[d_]:=Module[{
            (* secp256k1 *)
            p="p"/.secp256k1,
            a="a"/.secp256k1,b="b"/.secp256k1,
            xg="xg"/.secp256k1,yg="yg"/.secp256k1},

            ecProductMod[{a,b},{xg,yg},d,p]
        ];

        signECDSA[z_,d_]:=Module[{
            (* secp256k1 *)
            p="p"/.secp256k1,
            a="a"/.secp256k1,b="b"/.secp256k1,
            xg="xg"/.secp256k1,yg="yg"/.secp256k1,
            n="n"/.secp256k1,
            h="h"/.secp256k1,

            k,xp,yp,xh,yh,r=0,s=0},

            (* If s=0, then choose another k and try again *)
            While[s==0,

                (* If r=0, then choose another k and try again *)
                While[r==0,
                    k=Random[Integer,{1,n-1}];
                    {xp,yp}=ecProductMod[{a,b},{xg,yg},k,p];
                    r=Mod[xp,n] ;
                ];

                {xh,yh}=ecProductMod[{a,b},{xg,yg},d,p];
                s=Mod[PowerMod[k,-1,n] (Mod[z+r d,n]),n];
            ];

            (* The pair (r,s) is the signature *)
            {r,s}
        ];

        verifySignECDSA[z_,H:{xh_,yh_},{r_,s_}]:=Module[{
            (* secp256k1 *)
            p="p"/.secp256k1,
            a="a"/.secp256k1,b="b"/.secp256k1,
            xg="xg"/.secp256k1,yg="yg"/.secp256k1,
            n="n"/.secp256k1,

            u1,u2,xp,yp,w1,w2},

            (* Verify that the public address point lie on the curve *)
            If[!ecPointModQ[{a,b},H,p],Return[False]];

            u1=Mod[PowerMod[s,-1,n] z,n];
            u2=Mod[PowerMod[s,-1,n] r,n];

            w1=ecProductMod[{a,b},{xg,yg},u1,p];
            w2=ecProductMod[{a,b},{xh,yh},u2,p];

            {xp,yp}=ecAddMod[{a,b},w1,w2,p]; 

            (* The signature is valid only if  r = xp mod n *)
             r == Mod[xp,n]
        ]


    End[];
EndPackage[];
```

Comment: The first question seems off topic to me.  The second should be fine.

Comment: As for the second question, don't use `Module[{...}, ...; Return[res]; ]` .  Use `Module[{}, ...; res]`.  Consider making `secp256k1` an `Association` and use `asc["p"]` instead of `"p" /. asc`.  I can't comment more because I'm not familiar with these algorithms.

Comment: @Szabolcs *> "don't use `Module[{...}, ...; Return[res]; ]`"* This is related to functional programming vs procedural programming?

Comment: @Szabolcs *> "Use `Module[{}, ...; res]`."* Suppose I need to return a value before the end of the function (ex: `Module[{...}, If[..., Return[res];]; ...; res]`), is it fine to use `Return`?

Comment: @Szabolcs `> "The first question seems off topic to me."` Mind to explain why? It would be better to post it at "Cryptography Stack Exchange"?

Comment: @Szabolcs *> "Consider making `secp256k1` an `Association` and use `asc["p"]` instead of `"p" /. asc`."* Is there something similar for Mathematica 9.0?

Comment: It is my *opinion* that it is off topic, because it seems to be about the method and not about Mathematica.  I didn't vote or act otherwise on it. I do agree that it's unlikely that you'd get a response elsewhere because people on other sites tend not to know Mathematica. In general, you should be clear about what algorithm you want to implement, and then it is on-topic to ask how to do it best. But then we have numerical methods questions where people discuss the method more than the implementation, so ...

Comment: There are no associations in v9.0.  To comment more on your use of `/.`, see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130365/12) why Replace is better for this than ReplaceAll.  But given that your keys are all strings, this is really just nitpicking, and for this specific usecase, unimportant.

Comment: Is it the case that you already have an algorithm that you can describe in words, but want to make sure that the program does exactly that? If so, it may help if you describe it.  I don't know if this is feasible because I don't know these algorithms. Or are you not even sure about the algorithm that you are using?  In that case it is off topic and you should ask on Crypto.SE.  Also use pseudocode there, in case people don't know Mathematica.

Comment: @Szabolcs The algorithm I'm using is available in the links I've mentioned in the question. I'm pretty sure it works, the issue is whether I implemented correctly. It is possible to write a pseudocode, however, I would have to breakdown the question into ±5 other questions. I've considered doing that, but I've though that people would get more interested if they could see what the entire code could do. Let me know if you consider a good idea to breakdown this question in several others with the pseudocode for each one.

Comment: I wouldn't break it down.  Maybe someone who already know this stuff will check your code.  People who don't very likely won't read through all the material.  Your link is 84 pages long.

Comment: @Szabolcs *> "People who don't very likely won't read through all the material. Your link is 84 pages long."* I've just updated the link with another one much smaller than 84 pages. Let me know if you have any comments about it.

Comment: About good practice for programming in *Mathematica*, you may be interested in these two posts: [(18)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/31159), and [(109888)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109888/31159).

Comment: Perhaps worth a try: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @xavier *> "Perhaps worth a try: codereview.stackexchange.com"* Ok, just posted there: [SE codereview - ECDSA for Mathematica](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/146902/ecdsa-for-mathematica)

Comment: @xavier *> "About good practice for programming in Mathematica, you may be interested in these two posts: (18), and (109888)."* I've took a while to read both these posts, even so I've couldn't read them all completely.

Comment: Note that current versions of Wolfram Language have support for digital signatures, and private and public keys: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Cryptography.html